# Identify interface type/monitor mode using "/sys/class/net"

Tags: linux, wifi

Is it possible to tell what mode (monitor, managed etc) a wireless device is running in using `/sys/class/net`?

Is it possible to tell what the type is of an interface (wireless, ethernet etc) using `/sys/class/net`?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a wireless device, I've been able to tell the mode by looking at:
`/sys/class/net/<interface name>/type`

Then you can look up the type here:

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/uapi/linux/if_arp.h

Managed Mode:  Type = 1  (ARPHRD_ETHER)

Monitor Mode:  Type = 803 (ARPHRD_IEEE80211_RADIOTAP)